# Magento 2 EE getting error when we try to save order from the backend

Tags: magento-2.1.8, magento-ee

I have tried many solutions to fix this core issue. Whenever I am going to edit the order, update shipping or payment method and click on save. I am getting below error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getIsMultiShipping() on null in /var/www/html/project/vendor/magento/module-customer-balance/Observer/PaymentDataImportObserver.php:52 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/project/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(73): Magento\CustomerBalance\Observer\PaymentDataImportObserver->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer)) #1 /var/www/html/project/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(61): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Magento\CustomerBalance\Observer\PaymentDataImportObserver), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer)) #2 /var/www/html/project/vendor/magento/module-staging/Model/Event/Manager.php(97): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer)) #3 /var/www/html/project/var/generation/Magento/Staging/Model/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Staging\Model\Event\Manager->dispatch('sales_quote_pay...', Array) #4 /var/www/ht in /var/www/html/project/vendor/magento/module-customer-balance/Observer/PaymentDataImportObserver.php on line 52
```

I have debugged and came to know that Quote not generated properly. Due to that, I am getting this error. Please let us know if anyone has its solution to fix this issue.

Comment: If you are running EE there is pro support for you

Comment: Yes, already created a ticket in the support, they are looking into it since 8days.

Comment: Could need alot of looking into.  One option is to put it up on freelancer as a one time fix job.  Should not cost much

Comment: Thanks I don't have that option.

Comment: @Nits Have you found any solution?

Comment: Hi @Octopus yes I got the solution, I will update here tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nits

Comment: Most welcome @Octopus

Comment: we found the error in our logs as well but seems not easy to replicate. How do you edit order when magento only allows you to cancel and create a new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We got the solution for the above issue. In this issue, store not set up properly when we edit and save the order from the backend. So what I did, I have set an admin store when we edit and save the order. Please review the below code:

> /var/www/html/m218ee/app/code/Extension/Override/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\App\FrontControllerInterface">
        <plugin name="md_default_store_setter" type="Extension\Override\Plugin\DefaultStore" />
    </type>
```

> /var/www/html/Project/app/code/Extension/Override/Plugin/DefaultStore.php

```
namespace Module\Override\Plugin;

/**
 * Plugin to set default store for admin area.
 */
class DefaultStore
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * Initialize dependencies.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * Set current store for admin area
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\FrontController $subject
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     * @return void
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function beforeDispatch(
        \Magento\Framework\App\FrontControllerInterface $subject , \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ) {

        $path =  $request->getParams();
        if(!empty($path) && isset($path['namespace']) && $path['namespace']=='product_listing'){
            //Fixed default store issue in the product grid backend(previously showing default store value instead of admin store).
            $this->storeManager->setCurrentStore(\Magento\Store\Model\Store::ADMIN_CODE);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Please run below commands

> php bin/magento cache:flush or rm -rf var/*

If production mode is enable then you should run compilation command

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile

and if require run static-content command

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

I hope the above code help you.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate on why you need to change something in the product grid? The above error occurs when saving an order.